# Can not create a constraint

Tags: neo4j

My data looks like:

```
    user_id                             from_page_id        to_page_id          event_type  timestamp
0   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     pages/mine/mine     pv          1598936406406
1   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     /pages/score/score  pv          1598936408261
2   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     pages/mine/mine     click       1598936408311
3   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/mine/mine     /pages/score/score  click       1598936410824
4   USER355A155307089387404434774906    pages/score/score   /pages/scoreDetai   pv          1598936410878
...
```

I am trying to create a graph to connect the user with his visited pages path :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
CREATE (u:User), (p1:Page {from: line.from_page_id}), (p2:Page {to: line.to_page_id}),
(u)-[:VIEWS]->(p1), (u)-[:VIEWS]->(p2), (p1)-[:NEXT]->(p2);
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.id IS UNIQUE;
```

It creates graph, but it gives me error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintCreationFailed: Unable to create Constraint( name='constraint_47e7f15d', type='UNIQUENESS', schema=(:User {id}) ):
Both Node(324) and Node(327) have the label `User` and property `id` = 'USER0138119929164105321108358370'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think your mistake might be in not reading the error message? You're trying to add a constraint that user id is unique when in your data it visibly isn't. Either don't do the constraint (do you need it?) or get some other input data?

Comment: Do you get the graph what you wanted? Then just toss the constraint and move on. If the graph is not correct, you may want to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry I am totally newbie in neo4j, thank you, could you please kindly tell me what should I do to get the exact (distinct) user and his page path (view relationship)?

Comment: So you are trying to make a graph for one specific user?

Comment: And actually you currently know more about neo4j than me, I was just stating the painfully obvious. :)

Comment: Yes, there many users, and each view event (going from one page to another) is tracked in one row. I want to get the one user's path graph.

Comment: So your CSV has all users mixed and you want to filter it so that you get data for one specific user? (Is that correct?) A quick look at the documentation suggests that's done by a WHERE clause.

Comment: Just for info: the original 'unique' constraint meant that each row would have to have a different user id. Which seems to be the opposite of what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

What helps is this :

Create the CONSTRAINT in a separate process.. it does not have to be part of your cypher. Note that you can only create a CONSTRAINT if there are no duplicates.

Once the CONSTRAINT is there, Neo4j will check and prevent any duplicates to be inserted.

When you have the data as you have, you should use

```
MERGE (u:User {user_id:line.user_id})
```

More info here : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/